# Converting hex string to unsigned int issue C++

Tags: c++

I am currently designing a code and one of the instructions given is to get the first two digits of a hex string and do a desired operation. Everything that is less than A is taken into account. Anything greater than that is not, it just takes the next number. Which messes up the code.

Here is the line which converts it:

```
int x = atoi(hex.c_str);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using atoi.  (Read the spec.)

Comment: (Try strtol with base 16)

Comment: Ok, is there another instruction we can use to convert the hex string to unsigned int?

Comment: Now I'm getting `error: too few arguments to function `long int strtol(const char*, char**, int)'`

Comment: Failing to read the documentation, for a start >.<

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm assuming this is what you meant - you'd like to convert only the first two hexadecimal digits of a string to an unsigned integer. I'm also assuming that the string contains only valid hexadecimal digits. If you want to validate the string, you need to write some extra code for that.

Use `strtoul` to convert a hex string to unsigned integer instead. Also use `substr()` method of the string class to extract only the initial 2 digits of the hexadecimal string.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::string myhex = "abcdef";
    unsigned int x = strtoul(myhex.substr(0, 2).c_str(), NULL, 16);
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
}
```

This would be your output (i.e. `0xab = 171`):

```
x = 171
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = strtol(hex.c_str(), NULL, 16);
```

You can also use `sscanf` if you want to read a partial string.  You mentioned you might want to just take the first two characters:

```
int x;
if( 1 == sscanf(hex.c_str(), "%2x", &x) ) {
    printf( "Value is: %d\n", x );
} else {
    printf( "Conversion failed\n" );
}
```

Note the above isn't really C++.  You can use the `std::hex` stream modifier for that (note that I called your string `mystr` this time to avoid confusion (particularly if you've imported the namespace `std`):

```
int x;
std::istringstream iss(mystr);
bool ok = (iss >> std::hex >> x);
```

---

[edit] I notice in your comment you ask about converting to an *unsigned* integer.  In that case, why are you not explicitly declaring your integer as `unsigned int`?

For unsigned, you should use `strtoul`.

Answer (score 1):

the `atoi` function requires base 10

instead use e.g. `strtol`

it is generally a good idea to **read the documentation**. just write the function's name into [AltaVista](http://www.altavista.com/) (or, for that matter, google). and it will find some documentation for you

Comment: Wow!  I didn't know Altavista still existed!

Comment: It stopped existing on July 8, 2013 though. It just redirects to Yahoo!

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting to an unsigned, you probably want to use `strtoul` - either with a prefix of `0x` or giving a base of 16. It is possible that `strtol` also works correctly, but that is supposed to give a signed value, so at the very least you may get warnings for mixing signed and unsigned from some compilers.