# How to create a pointer to a buffer from char []

Tags: c++, pointers, char, buffer

If you have the memory address of a buffer, and this address is stored in a char, for example: 
`char bufferAddress[] = "0024ABC3"`, how can you create a pointer using `bufferAddress` so that you can access variables in the buffer?

Comment: but this is 256-bit addressing.

Comment: @huseyin: There are only 32 bits in the OP's example.  Basically, he wants to get a 32 bit number from a string hexadecimal representation, which is a fairly pedestrian conversion.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148495

Comment: Convert that number to a `unsigned long` and cast it to `char*` :P ...

Comment: @user3800036 See my answer. It shows how to do the task.

Comment: I hope this is for a debug watch window or the equivalent, since pointer values tend to only be valid for a single execution of the process.

Comment: It gets a new pointer every time the program runs - Game Maker Studio is dumping some game data into a buffer, then passing the buffer address in string form to a DLL (GM Studio forces the address to be in string form). The DLL converts the string address into a pointer, then uses the pointer to access game data in the buffer.

Comment: That seems... odd.  If it can pass a pointer to the string containing the buffer address, why can't it pass a pointer to the buffer?

Comment: Basically GM Studio can only pass types "string" and "real". I get the buffer address using [buffer_get_address](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/buffers/buffer_get_address.html), convert it to a string, then pass it to the DLL. Then the DLL converts it from a string to a pointer in order to access the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get the string into a number, then you can try something like this:

```
void *ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*> (0x0024ABC3);
```

There are a few other threads on here that deal with assigning addresses to pointers directly, so you could check those out as well. Here's one: [How to initialize a pointer to a specific memory address in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934775/how-to-initialize-a-pointer-to-a-specific-memory-address-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You can do the task using `std::istringstream`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() 
{
    char bufferAddress[] = "0024ABC3";
    std::istringstream is( bufferAddress );
    void *p;

    is >> p;

    std::cout << "p = " << p << std::endl;  

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
p = 0x24abc3
```

If the buffer has type `char *` then you can reinterpret this pointer to void to pointer to char. For example

```
char *buffer = reinterpret_cast<char *>( p );
```

Comment: I'd sure like to know why people disagree with this answer.

Comment: @Ben Voigt All is very simple. Those who down-voted simply do not know that there is an overloaded operator >> for type void *. :)

Comment: It's probably that simple, but just in case someone has a legitimate objection I'd like to hear it.

Comment: @Ben Voigt  i very doubt that you will hear a legitimate objection. Those who down-voted will prefer to keep silence.:)